# How to select first NOT NULL Value?

Tags: sql

Eg : Table

COL1 COL2  COL3

ADAM  NULL AAA

NULL  EVE  BBB

NULL  NULL CCC

How to select first NOT NULL value?
Please suggest. Thanks!!!

Comment: Which server? What exactly do you want as output? First non-null value per row or per column? Please give an example output.

Comment: Quality is too poor to merit migration to [so]. Remember: *please don't migrate crap*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the first value that is not NULL, you can use `COALESCE`:

```
select coalesce(col1, col2, col3) from table
```

It will still give you NULL if col1 and col2 and col3 are NULL.